# Eclipse shuts dows immediately every time I run it after installing Team Explorer Everywhere

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere

After installing Team Explorer Everywhere plugin Eclipse oxygen shuts dows right after it has been loaded. I have JRE installed version 1.8.0_131. Windows 7 64 OS, 2 GB of RAM. I have installed GIT before that and appended to the path of system variables C:\Program Files\Git\cmd. I also have HOME environment variable set with the variable value C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131.
Once Eclipse wrote the following text in .log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-07-14 10:14:17.583
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.util.TeamUtils", thread "Thread[Worker-5,5,main]" timed out waiting (5248ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-3,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse_14.119.2.201706191916 [552]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-5,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.util.TeamUtils" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="14.119.2.201706191916"; osgi.identity="com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse"; singleton:="true" [id=552] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.project.ProjectRepositoryManager.shouldConnect(ProjectRepositoryManager.java:529)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.project.ProjectRepositoryManager.start(ProjectRepositoryManager.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.TFSEclipseClientPlugin$1.run(TFSEclipseClientPlugin.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting 5 seconds to acquire the lock.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:334)
    ... 15 more
Root exception:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout after waiting 5 seconds to acquire the lock.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.project.ProjectRepositoryManager.shouldConnect(ProjectRepositoryManager.java:529)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.project.ProjectRepositoryManager.start(ProjectRepositoryManager.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.client.eclipse.TFSEclipseClientPlugin$1.run(TFSEclipseClientPlugin.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below ways to fix that:

- Remove the **.Lock** file from your workspace **.metadata** folder.
- Remove the **.fileTableLock** file under

  C:\Users{your
     account}\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager
- Set the following flag in your **eclipse.ini** ***(normally should be under C:\Users{your account}\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse)*** file to increase the
  osgi timeout value from 5 seconds to 2 minutes to prevent osgi from
  timing out out too quickly.

  -Dequinox.statechange.timeout=120000
- Set the following flat in your **eclipse.ini** file to ignore
  checking the configuration.

  -Dosgi.checkConfiguration=false
- Go to your workspace directory and perform the following steps:

  1. Naviagate to **.metadata/.plugins**
  2. Rename **org.eclipse.core.resources** to **org.eclipse.core.resources.bak**. (backup it)
  3. Start eclipse. (It should show an error message or an empty workspace because no project is found.)
  4. Close all open editors tabs.
  5. Exit eclipse.
  6. Delete **org.eclipse.core.resources** (Delete the newly created directory.)
  7. Rename **org.eclipse.core.resources.bak** back to **org.eclipse.core.resources** (Restore the original directory.)
  8. Start eclipse and start working.

Comment: @KosTTTT Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update for this?

Comment: No, too much things to do. I will not ask my friends to do it even if it works. Decided not to use this Team Explorer Everywhere. It works fine with win 10 though. Thank you.